# php script hanging up because of curl

Tags: curl

This script is causing my php file to hang:

```
$handle   = curl_init($pictureimg); 
    $connectable = curl_exec($handle);
    curl_close($handle);
```

Any idea why? It was working a few days ago. Then I think I accidentally changed a setting somewhere, and all my curls have stopped working.

Comment: btw, i know that $pictureimg is a correct url

Answer (score 0):

Does php wait while executing a CURL request? Maybe the other server is getting low on resources.